# WSO2 DSS and JSON columns

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have a `Cassandra` table with 2 columns: **"id"** and **"Data"**. *Data* column contain a `JSON` data (*near 30kb size*).

When I use `DSS SOAP` to retrive this data it works fine just **for one record**. If I try to select **2-5 records** it works **very slowly** and if I select more than **5 records `DSS` is hung up**.

The **same effect** in case when I use `MySQL`.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried with REST with JSON ?

Comment: Not yet, but I have large existing app and I don't want to change SOAP to REST.

Comment: Any ideas? I think the cause of this behavior - escaping special chars, but even in this case it is too slowly.